# Handling multiple nested cursors in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How can I use two cursors in the same routine? I am getting "Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration" error while creating procedure.
I have to use both integer outerDone & innerDone to check whether cursor points to null or not.
I haven't worked on stored-procedure yet. Could anybody sort this problem please. Thanks in advance!!

```
DELIMITER ##;
create procedure updateStopTimeColumn()
BEGIN
DECLARE outerDone INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE vehicle_record CURSOR FOR SELECT `vehicleId` FROM `vehicle`;
DECLARE current_record CURSOR FOR SELECT `id`,`tsTime`,`teTime` FROM `trip` where `vehicleId`=vehId order by `tsTime`;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET outerDone = 1;
DECLARE vehId,tripId CHAR(250);
DECLARE currentTsTime,currentTeTime time;

OPEN vehicle_record;
REPEAT  
    FETCH vehicle_record INTO vehId;


block2 : BEGIN
    DECLARE innerDone INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tempTripId CHAR(250);
    DECLARE tempTsTime,tempTeTime time;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET innerDone = 1;

    OPEN current_record;

    FETCH current_record INTO tempTripId, tempTsTime,tempTeTime;

    REPEAT
        FETCH current_record INTO tripId,currentTsTime,currentTeTime;
        UPDATE trip set stopTime=(currentTeTime-tempTsTime) where id=tempTripId and tempTeTime IS NOT NULL;

        SET tempTripId=tempId;
        SET tempTsTime=currentTsTime;
        SET tempTeTime=currentTeTime;

    UNTIL innerDone END REPEAT;
END block2;
CLOSE current_record;
UNTIL outerDone END REPEAT;

CLOSE vehicle_record;
END; ##
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: If possible, can you create a SQL Fiddle, [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for your problem? It just makes it much easier to test solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving the

```
DECLARE vehId,tripId CHAR(250);
DECLARE currentTsTime,currentTeTime time;
```

statements to before your cursors?